# How to get the Checked attribute values in xslt refer to the xml format

Tags: xslt

Can any body please help me to get all the checked='Y' attribute value in xslt transformation
My xml file:

```
<ReviewSummaryXML>

<CP Checked="Y" ID="TOP" Txt="Initial, Both:" />
<CP ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness">
    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness,  All:">
       <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010202" Txt="Clinical presentation, &gt;= One:">
         <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020201" Txt="Illness / Injury / Exacerbation / Surgery &lt;= 30d" />
         <CP ID="HMC0001020202" Txt="Discharged from inpatient facility" />
         <CP ID="HMC0001020203" Txt="End-stage disease / Hospice / Palliative care" />
        </CP>
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010203" Txt="Skilled assessment / intervention required, &gt;= One:">
          <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020301" Txt="Adherence assessment" />
          <CP ID="HMC0001020302" Txt="Adjustments in treatment / medication regimen" />
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020303" Txt="Management and evaluation of care plan, Both:">
              <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030301" Txt="Active comorbidity" />
              <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030302" Txt="Multiple unskilled care needs" />
            </CP>
            <CP ID="HMC0001020304" Txt="New / Change in caregiver" />
            <CP ID="HMC0001020305" Txt="New onset symptoms" />
            <CP ID="HMC0001020306" Txt="New treatment / medication regimen" />
            <CP ID="HMC0001020307" Txt="Suspected safety / environmental issues in patient&apos;s home" />
        </CP>
       .........
</ReviewSummaryXML>
```

Expected output:

Initial, Both:
Severity of Illness,  All:Clinical presentation, >= One:
Clinical presentation, >= One:
Skilled assessment / intervention required, >=`enter code here` One:
Adherence assessment
............

Comment: I think you want to select `//CP[@Checked = 'Y']/@Txt`. As for the output, it depends on whether you want plain text or HTML or another format and whether you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen for your response.                                                                           I m getting only the first <CP> tag value not all checked attribute value. Please share me if you any idea.

Comment: Well, please show us your relevant XSLT you currently have, if you use XSLT 1.0 then `xsl:value-of` outputs the string value of only the first selected node, so you would need to write a template matching each node or process them with `for-each`, with XSLT 2.0 however it suffices to use `<xsl:value-of select="//CP[@Checked = 'Y']/@Txt" separator="&#10;"/>`.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ReviewSummaryXML" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ReviewSummaryXML">
      <xsl:value-of select="CP[@Checked = 'Y']/@Txt" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have shared the xslt file please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the nodes you are interested in with apply-templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head> </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//CP[@Checked = 'Y']/@Txt"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@Txt">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the input

```
<ReviewSummaryXML>

    <CP Checked="Y" ID="TOP" Txt="Initial, Both:" />
    <CP ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness">
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness,  All:">
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010202" Txt="Clinical presentation, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020201" Txt="Illness / Injury / Exacerbation / Surgery &lt;= 30d" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020202" Txt="Discharged from inpatient facility" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020203" Txt="End-stage disease / Hospice / Palliative care" />
            </CP>
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010203" Txt="Skilled assessment / intervention required, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020301" Txt="Adherence assessment" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020302" Txt="Adjustments in treatment / medication regimen" />
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020303" Txt="Management and evaluation of care plan, Both:">
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030301" Txt="Active comorbidity" />
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030302" Txt="Multiple unskilled care needs" />
                </CP>
                <CP ID="HMC0001020304" Txt="New / Change in caregiver" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020305" Txt="New onset symptoms" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020306" Txt="New treatment / medication regimen" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020307" Txt="Suspected safety / environmental issues in patient&apos;s home" />
            </CP>
        </CP>
    </CP>
            .........
</ReviewSummaryXML>
```

I get the output

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>Initial, Both:<br>Severity of Illness,  All:<br>Clinical presentation, &gt;= One:<br>Illness / Injury / Exacerbation / Surgery &lt;= 30d<br>Skilled assessment / intervention required, &gt;= One:<br>Adherence assessment<br>Management and evaluation of care plan, Both:<br>Active comorbidity<br>Multiple unskilled care needs<br></body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting this error : Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Comment: i am getting the output up to certain level, I would like to have all the checked values.                                                                                        Output:                                                                                                        Initial, Both:
Severity of Illness, All:
Clinical presentation, >= One:

Comment: @Baikuntha, I have shown the results I get for the input sample completed from your snippet in the question. If you still have problems, then edit your question and show minimal but complete sample of input, output you want, output you get, together with an explanation of the criteria you want to select nodes by.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

here is my complete xml strutcture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviewSummaryXML>
    <CP Checked="Y" ID="TOP" Txt="Initial, Both:" />
    <CP ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness">
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102" Txt="Severity of Illness,  All:">
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010202" Txt="Clinical presentation, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020201" Txt="Illness / Injury / Exacerbation / Surgery &lt;= 30d" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020202" Txt="Discharged from inpatient facility" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020203" Txt="End-stage disease / Hospice / Palliative care" />
            </CP>
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010203" Txt="Skilled assessment / intervention required, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020301" Txt="Adherence assessment" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020302" Txt="Adjustments in treatment / medication regimen" />
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020303" Txt="Management and evaluation of care plan, Both:">
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030301" Txt="Active comorbidity" />
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102030302" Txt="Multiple unskilled care needs" />
                </CP>
                <CP ID="HMC0001020304" Txt="New / Change in caregiver" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020305" Txt="New onset symptoms" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020306" Txt="New treatment / medication regimen" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020307" Txt="Suspected safety / environmental issues in patient's home" />
            </CP>
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010204" Txt="Patient / Caregiver unable to manage care, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020401" Txt="Cognitive deficit" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020402" Txt="Knowledge deficit" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020403" Txt="Physical deficit" />
            </CP>
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010205" Txt="Care required in the home setting, &gt;= One:">
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020501" Txt="Homebound, &gt;= One:">
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102050101" Txt="Requires &gt;= minimum assistance in transfers / bed mobility / locomotion to leave home / residence" />
                    <CP ID="HMC000102050102" Txt="DOE &lt;= 20 ft(6.1 m) ambulation" />
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102050103" Txt="Activity restrictions, &gt;= One:">
                        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010205010301" Txt="BR / BR with BRP" />
                        <CP ID="HMC00010205010302" Txt="NYHA Class III / IV" />
                        <CP ID="HMC00010205010303" Txt="Isolation and immunocompromised / communicable disease" />
                    </CP>
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102050104" Txt="Failed past attempt(s) at OP care, &gt;= One:">
                        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010205010401" Txt="Incapacitating mental illness" />
                        <CP ID="HMC00010205010402" Txt="Severe physical impairment" />
                    </CP>
                    <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000102050105" Txt="Significant memory loss, &gt;= One:">
                        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010205010501" Txt="Jeopardizes safety through actions" />
                        <CP ID="HMC00010205010502" Txt="Requires continuous supervision" />
                    </CP>
                </CP>
                <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC0001020502" Txt="In lieu of facility-based care" />
                <CP ID="HMC0001020503" Txt="OP management contraindicated / unavailable" />
            </CP>
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010206" Txt="Patient / Caregiver agree and are able to participate in the home care program" />
        </CP>
    </CP>
    <CP ID="HMC000104" Txt="Intensity of Service">
        <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC000104" Txt="Intensity of Service,  &gt;= One:">
            <CP Checked="Y" ID="HMC00010402" Txt="Initial assessment for skilled need 1 visit" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010403" Txt="Home environment &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010404" Txt="Bladder, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010405" Txt="Bowel &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 1 wk, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010406" Txt="Cardiovascular &lt;= 8 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010407" Txt="Diabetes &lt;= 6 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010408" Txt="Feeding tube (new insertion) and inability to correct with oral intake &lt;= 10 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010409" Txt="Hematology &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010410" Txt="Hospice / Palliative care per protocol" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010411" Txt="Injections IM / SC &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010412" Txt="Medical social services consult for inadequate resources / supports interfering with medical progress &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010413" Txt="Neurologic &lt;= 6 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010414" Txt="Nutrition consult for high risk patients &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010415" Txt="Pain management &lt;= 6 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010416" Txt="Peripheral vascular &lt;= 6 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010417" Txt="Psychiatric nursing &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010418" Txt="Respiratory &lt;= 6 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
            <CP ID="HMC00010419" Txt="Skin &lt;= 2 visits &lt;= 2 wks, &gt;= One:" />
        </CP>
    </CP>
    <CP ID="HMC000106" Txt="Discharge">
        <CP ID="HMC000106" Txt="Discharge,  &gt;= One:" />
    </CP>
</ReviewSummaryXML>
```

Comment: Please help me to get all the checked attribute values.